# unresolved external symbol WSASetSocketSecurity

Tags: c++, windows, sockets

I'm trying to add some security to a socket connection. I am linking with ws2_32.lib. This is a test program that illustrates the problem. Its a windows c++ console app, compiled for x64. It compiles properly but won't link.

What am I missing?

Thanks,
Gerry

```
#include <iostream>
#include <WinSock2.h>
#include <mstcpip.h>
#include <WS2tcpip.h>

int main()
{
    std::cout << "Hello World!\n";

    SOCKET listener;
    int err;

    listener = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
    if (listener == INVALID_SOCKET)
    {
        exit(0);
    }

    SOCKET_SECURITY_SETTINGS ssettings = {
        SOCKET_SECURITY_PROTOCOL_IPSEC,
        SOCKET_SETTINGS_ALLOW_INSECURE
    };
    err = WSASetSocketSecurity(listener,
        &ssettings, sizeof(SOCKET_SECURITY_SETTINGS), NULL, NULL);
    if (err == SOCKET_ERROR) {
        int iResult = WSAGetLastError();
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As written in the Requirements section of the [documentation of the `WSASetSocketSecurity` function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/ws2tcpip/nf-ws2tcpip-wsasetsocketsecurity), you need to link with `Fwpuclnt.lib`.